# How can I filter group and do aggregation when it does/does not have a specific value?

Tags: sql, group-by

Sample data

```
id1 | id2 | id3 | col1 | col2
-----------------------------
113 | 10  | 100 |   8  |  10
113 | 10  | 100 |   8  |  20
113 | 10  | 100 |   6  |  30
114 | 10  | 200 |   5  |  40
114 | 10  | 200 |   6  |  50
115 | 10  | 250 |   4  |  60
116 | 10  | 300 |   2  |  70
```

Desired Result:

```
id1 | id2 |  output
------------------
113 | 10  |   70
114 | 10  |   200
115 | 10  |   250
116 | 10  |   300
```

The calculation goes like this.

- For each combination of `id1`, `id2` - if there exists a value `8` in subgroup of `col1`, then I should take only the particular group which has `8`, then do `output = id3 - sum(col2)`. Explaining this further, for `id1=113` and `id2=10` there exists two subgroups `8` and `6` in `col1`. I should take **only** the subgroup `8` and do the aggregation. If `8` does not exist in the subgroup then see the below bullet point.
- If such a `8` does not exist in the subgroup, I should do `output = id3`.
- NOTE - `id3` is unique for each pair of `id1` and `id2`.

I am stuck with how to use a `group by` for this with such a filter condition. Engine I'm using is SPARK-SQL. I prefer to use SQL and no commands which are vendor specific.

I asked a similar thing in this [question at dba stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227942/how-to-use-case-and-filter-with-a-group-by-statement-and-having-an-aggregate-cal)

Comment: I could not understand id 114's output

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `id1` INTEGER,
  `id2` INTEGER,
  `id3` INTEGER,
  `col1` INTEGER,
  `col2` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`id1`, `id2`, `id3`, `col1`, `col2`)
VALUES
  ('113', '10', '100', '8', '10'),
  ('113', '10', '100', '8', '20'),
  ('113', '10', '100', '6', '30'),
  ('114', '10', '200', '5', '40'),
  ('114', '10', '200', '6', '50'),
  ('115', '10', '250', '4', '60'),
  ('116', '10', '300', '2', '70');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select 
  id1, 
  id2, 
  sum(distinct id3) - sum(case when col1 = 8 then col2 else 0 end) output
from table1
group by id1, id2;
```

**Output**

```
| id1 | id2 | output |
| --- | --- | ------ |
| 113 | 10  | 70     |
| 114 | 10  | 200    |
| 115 | 10  | 250    |
| 116 | 10  | 300    |
```

---

<kbd>[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pqUGYfTeaKbEHKPv4mWeWL/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    id1,
    MAX(id2) AS id2,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN col1 = 8 THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN MAX(id3) - SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = 8 THEN col2 ELSE 0 END)
         ELSE MAX(id3) END AS output
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    id1;
```

[image]

### Demo